# Change Storage Account Name Synapse Serverless

Tags: devops, serverless, azure-synapse

When I deploy my dacpac file from dev to test my Synapse Serverless external tables still point to the dev storage account name and not the test storage account name.

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE [ADLSGold] WITH (LOCATION = N'https://**devstorageaccountname**.blob.core.windows.net/gold/', CREDENTIAL = [AdlsCredentials])

Do you know the best way to change this:

1. Is it possible to change this as part of the deployment in devops when I publish the dacpac file
2. Do I need something to run after deployment to make the change in the test environment.

Thanks

Tried to Alter the external data source but this didn't work.

I can't drop and recreate the external data source as there are external tables referencing the source